# Storing line-by-line data in single database field

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database

In MySQL database, I have a table in which there is a field named features. I have nearly 20 features to store there. I am trying to retrieve these features from my Android mobile application. In app, it has to be shown as line by line (so 20 lines in total). Is there anyway to store the 20 features in that single field by doing something like `\n`? Or is there anyway to get those features in new lines by doing something in my android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this is almost certainly a terrible idea...by storing the features in a single field, you make it very hard to query and manage. For instance, finding all records where feature "x" is available requires you to parse the feature field in some way, which will almost certainly not make use of any indexing on the column.

If you have no choice, you have two options: store the features as some kind of string representation (XML, JSON, CSV), or store the features as a bit flag.

I strongly recommend using a structured text format - JSON is probably the most lightweight - because it's human readable, and easily parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you have the code set up to run a query and retrieve the data, you should store the data retrieved into a collection (an array or list) and loop through each item, displaying the needed data on the screen.

Displaying the data can work anyway you want, you can add a button for each record, write a line of text to a text field (which is probably good for your case), create a cell in a table etc....

I wouldn't place all of the data into the same record, it could get messy should you decide to add a field which is tailored to an individual feature. Plus, if you combine all the features into one record and decide to add or remove a feature later on, you will have to do string manipulation.

Comment: thanx for the reply..but how do I loop through each item? How can I categorize them ?

Answer (score -1):

I would go with **LONGTEXT**.  TEXT and BLOB can hold 64K of data while **LONGTEXT** and **LONGBLOB** (used primarily for binary data) can hold up to 4GB.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

And yes, /n is fine for line delimiting